# Why should I password protect WP-Admin?

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess

Just occured to me: what's the point of password protecting www.yoursite.com/wp-admin when a user can just type www.yoursite.com/wp-login.php, bypassing the password on /wp-admin?

Am I missing something here? I've ready many blogs/posts that suggest adding this extra layer of protection to wp-admin using .htaccess/.htpasswd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The protection from .htaccess is for the folder `/wp-admin`  it's not for the URL

Open up your ftp programme (or download WordPress) and look inside /wp-admin

By only allowing your IP access this folder you're blocking a lot of possible exploit issues (as mentioned in comments below).

I always prefer to login at `mysite.com/wp-admin`  and not login.php  this way, if you're still logged in to your site, you go straight to the Admin section.

Comment: This also blocks bots or hooligans from posting to admin-ajax.php.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I've gone ahead and password-protected wp-admin on my live server, but when I go to mysite.com/wp-admin, I receive a "Too many redirects error" - status 310. What does this mean and how can I fix it? Chrome's suggestion (clearing cache, allowing third-party cookies, etc.) did not solve this problem.

Comment: Hi mark remove the .httpswd protection and just have .htaccess with your ip address. You're probably blocking Wordpress processing functions with the password

Answer (score 0):

Even accessing www.yoursite.com/wp-login.php will still prompt you for password. It's a good way to add another security layer on your site. The problem here is that you need to add a font-end login and registration if you need user to login.